# PayPal Rest api sdk

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, paypal

I have implemented paypal sdk in android. When I execute paypal in android using paypal sdk they give me a reponse json.

```
 "response": {
"state": "approved",
"id": "PAY-7075194003318564GKZZINNA",
"create_time": "2015-12-17T09:56:20Z",
"intent": "sale"
},
"client": {
"platform": "Android",
"paypal_sdk_version": "2.12.4",
"product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK",
"environment": "sandbox"
},
"response_type": "payment"
}
```

In asp .net I receive paypal id. I want to get payment details and execute the payment. I am using paypal sdk for .net.

```
var payment = Payment.Get(apiContext, paymentId);
            if (payment.state.Equals("approved"))
            {
                var paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution();
                paymentExecution.payer_id = payment.payer.payer_info.payer_id;
                Payment newPayment = payment.Execute(apiContext, paymentExecution);
                //var firstOrDefault = payment.transactions.FirstOrDefault();
                //if (firstOrDefault != null)
                //{
                //    string amount = firstOrDefault.amount.total;
                //}

            }
```

But everytime I got an error named 400 bad request at calling payment.execute function. Also I dont get the details of payment(Payment.Get give error) after 3 hour of excuting payment from android. Why data lost after 3 hour? 
Do I need to excute paypal payment if state is approved?
I am using sandbox now for testing